# Materialize CSS Sidenav open from bottom of screen

Tags: javascript, css, materialize

Does anyone know how to get the sidenav in Materialize CSS to slide open from the bottom of the screen?

It only has the option for left or right:

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('.sidenav').sidenav({
      edge: 'left', // Choose the horizontal origin
    });
  });
```

Comment: The M sidenav is limited to left or right, and that decision is based on best UX. You could hack the js and css to do what you need, or they have some other components that can be more easily attached to the bottom of the screen https://materializecss.com/floating-action-button.html

Comment: Thanks @SeanDoherty I dont mind the button, I want the actual menu to slide up from the bottom of the screen. Spoiler alert, kinda like the Windows 11 start menu. I have seen many examples where people makes the menu jump from bottom -650 to bottom 50, but that doesnt work if you want to keep scrolling on.

Comment: the slide in menu is a very simple thing. Any div with a fixed position pushed off the screen in any direction, and then reset to the original position on activation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that this isn't really possible without setting max-heights for the page, so if there is content below, it won't be shown if you force a max-height and then bring the menu up from below the max-height.

So, the answer is no if you have content more than one window long.